# Podio Authentication: how to use the scope parameter

Tags: php, authentication, podio

[Here is the relevant part of the documentation](https://developers.podio.com/authentication/scopes). I want to make sure an authenticated user has access to a 'space' on Podio before I redirect them but nothing is working so far...

I have tried adding this to the URL

```
&scope=space_3293195:read
&scope=3293195:read
&scope=thename:read
```

but it's not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but scope's feature is currently in Beta only and therefore not available for all Podio users.

> We still have some work to do on the granular authentication project
>   before we are able to release to public. Would love your feedback
>   about how would you use scopes as this will help us come closer to a
>   public release!

Comment: That really Sucked that I couldn't use it.  I ended up try {access a space} with the authenticated user and if it had access show